# Python recursion with list returns None

Tags: python, list, recursion

```
def foo(a):
    a.append(1)
    if len(a) > 10:
        print a
        return a
    else:
        foo(a)
```

Why this recursive function returns None (see transcript below)? I can't quite understand what I am doing wrong.

```
In [263]: x = []

In [264]: y = foo(x)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

In [265]: print y
None
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't return anything in the `else` clause:

```
    else:
        return foo(a)
```