# updating python list on recurison call returns None

Tags: python

```
def get_name():
    import random
    lst = ["aa", "bbb", "ccc", "dddd", "eee", "stop"]
    return random.choice(lst)

def poi(name, lst):
    res = get_name()
    lst.append(res)
    if res !="stop":
        poi(name, lst)
    else:
        print lst
        return lst


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print poi("xx", [])
```

`poi()` method add items in a passed list and should return list until "stop" is in the list. If "stop" is in the list then returns the list

`print lst` prints  `['bbb', 'dddd', 'bbb', 'stop']`    #1

But

```
`print poi("xx", [])` prints `None`  #2
```

Why `#2` is printing `None` instead of updated list ?

Comment: Or e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2599149/3001761, or http://stackoverflow.com/q/15210646/3001761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
poi(name, lst)
```

should be

```
return poi(name, lst)
```

Without the `return` statement, the function is implicitly returning `None`.