# Python recursion returns None

Tags: python, recursion

This will be really funny...
Given following `python` codes:

```
def getBinary(binaryInput, kSize, beginBit):
    if int(binaryInput[beginBit + kSize-1])==1:
        print 'entered!!!'
        shortE = binaryInput[beginBit:kSize+beginBit]
        print 'shortE is now: ', shortE
        print 'kSize is now: ', kSize
        return (shortE,kSize)
    else :
        print 'else entered...'
        kSize -=1
        getBinary(binaryInput, kSize, beginBit)

result = getBinary("{0:b}".format(6), 3, 0)
print result
```

The output is:

```
else entered...
entered!!!
shortE is now:  11
kSize is now:  2
None
```

I mean since `shortE` is 11 and `kSize` is 2, why the return value is `None`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python recursion with list returns None](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599149/python-recursion-with-list-returns-none)

Comment: Why people like finding `duplicate` so much? @PeterWood

Comment: @Liquid Because it is helpful to everybody. Including, and especially, you.

Comment: @Liquid Because I saw someone ask exactly the same question the other day, and it had been asked 5 years ago. This place is great as a resource for others because of the density of good answers to specific questions. You're watering it down; I'm trying to thicken it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function ends without executing a `return` statement, it returns `None`. Instead of

```
getBinary(binaryInput, kSize, beginBit)
```

you mean

```
return getBinary(binaryInput, kSize, beginBit)
```

Comment: But why it does not executing `return`? From the console output, I can tell that the in the second time, the function go into the `if` statement and calculate the value of `shortE` and `keySize`, and then it should go to the `return` statement and return the according value, right?

Comment: The else is entered on the outer most call, and that's the one that returns and assigns to `result`.

Answer (score 1):

The code is missing in the `else` part:

```
def getBinary(binaryInput, kSize, beginBit):
    if int(binaryInput[beginBit + kSize-1])==1:
        print 'entered!!!'
        shortE = binaryInput[beginBit:kSize+beginBit]
        print 'shortE is now: ', shortE
        print 'kSize is now: ', kSize
        return (shortE,kSize)
    else :
        print 'else entered...'
        kSize -=1
        return getBinary(binaryInput, kSize, beginBit)
        # ^^^^
```