# Python embedded function returns None

Tags: python-2.7, function

I have a very simple function which summarize the list elements without using `sum` function or looping technique. Here it is:

```
def find_sum(mylist):
    def get_value(sublist, counter):
        counter += sublist.pop()
        if sublist:
            get_value(sublist, counter)
        else:
            print counter              # It will print correct result 
            return counter
    my_sum = get_value(mylist, 0)      # But my_sum is None
    return my_sum
```

Why the emdedded function returns None?

Comment: You need "return get_value(sublist, counter)" in your "if sublist:", because without return statement, it will evaluate, but not return value.

Comment: O! Thanks! It's working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python recursion with list returns None](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599149/python-recursion-with-list-returns-none)