# Why Recursive function return "None"

Tags: python

Below code returns "None"
But, when I change (return sum) to (return
print(sum)) it returns right value.
Why does this problem occur?

```
def good(num,sum):
    if num == 0:
        return sum
    sum = sum + num
    num = num - 1
    good(num,sum)

sum = 0
a = 3
k = good(a,sum)
print(k)
```

Comment: Your recursive case has no return statement. Try `return good(num, sum)` in the last line of the function.

Comment: "But, when I change (return sum) to (return print(sum)) it returns right value." **No, it does not**. You will notice that `k` does not get the correct value this way. `print` only causes things to be *displayed on the screen*; it has **nothing to do with** returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement is missing!

Do this:

```
def good(num,sum):

    if num == 0:
        return sum
    sum = sum + num
    num = num - 1
    return good(num, sum)
```

This is because the function is called but is not returning the new values recursively.

One of the best website that explains this in depth and clearly is **realpython.com,** have a look especially at: [maintaining-state](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/#maintaining-state) but I suggest you to have a look at the whole article.

For sake of completeness I quote a section where I think is related to the issue you encountered:

> Behind the scenes, each recursive call adds a stack frame (containing its execution context) to the call stack until we reach the base case. Then, the stack begins to **unwind** as each call returns its results.

- unwind: Basically it returns it backward.

> When dealing with recursive functions, **keep in mind that each recursive call has its own execution context.**

### Other Stack Overflow Related questions

- [recursive-function-returning-none-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215141/recursive-function-returning-none-in-python)
- [python-recursion-with-list-returns-none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599149/python-recursion-with-list-returns-none)
- [i-expect-true-but-get-none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210646/i-expect-true-but-get-none)